# A button with re-captcha on a page has to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, recaptcha

I'm using re-captcha in my web application, it approximately looks like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your name" required="true" />
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="123abcd" data-size="invisible" data-badge="inline"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
```

And:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

And ajax request:

```
document.getElementById("my_form123").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.execute();
  var grecap_resp = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if (grecap_resp.length !== 0) {
    // sending ajax request my server to sign up

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //..............
  } else {
    return false;
  };
```

The issue is that the button "submit" never responds to the 1st click and thus I have to click the 2nd time on it to sign up. What can be the cause?

Comment: probably you need another event to bind onsubmit event (when form is ready in dom). otherwise give try with setTimeout.

Comment: @Aman, why?..........

Comment: I don't see an element with id `my_form123` in your code. Please add it.